# Spring SPEL expression, access nested interface String constants

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

i use nested interfaces to store String constants :

```
public interface Constants{
    interface level1 {
        interface level2 {
            String CONSTANT = "constant";
        }
    }
}
```

I want to inject these constants into a spring value field, i have tried :

```
 <entry key="key" value="#{com.company.Constants.level1.level2.CONSTANT}"/>
 <entry key="key" value="#{T(com.company.Constants.level1.level2).CONSTANT}"/>
```

But it's not working, what is the proper way ?

Answer (score 6):

When you compile your code the `Constants` interface compiles into 3 class files:

[image]

and that's because the `level1` nested interface compiles into a classfile with name `Constants$level1` and the `level2` nested-nested interface compiles into classfile with name `Constants$level1$level2`.

Now that you know how to refer to the second nested `level2` retrieve the constant as follows:

```
<entry key="key" value="#{T(com.company.Constants$level1$level2).CONSTANT}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Internal classes are normally separated by the $ sign and not by dot.

To get the correct T(...) value just call: level2.class.getName() in java and use this value.

But im not sure if the interface needs to be declared public to be able to work in SPEL.

Comment: I can't find any reference to $ in SPeL documentation, and it's not working.

Comment: Whats the output if you do the call i wrote in a simple main method?

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly for me.
I am using it in @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority(T(package.TheClass$NestedInterface1$NestedInterface2$NestedInterface3).Constant)")

It works but, unfortunately, it is very verbose..

Comment: I am now using another way
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('"+Constants.NestedInterface.Constant+"')")